# Tricky SQL query requiring search for contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data such as this:

Inventors column in my table

```
Hundley; Edward; Ana
Isler; Hunsberger
Hunsberger;Hundley
```

Names are separated by ;. I want to write a SQL query which sums up the count.

Eg. The result should be:

```
Hundley     2
Isler       1
Hunsberger  2
Edward      1
Ana         1
```

I could do a group by but this is not a simple group by as you can see. Any ideas/thoughts on how to get this output?

**Edit:** Changed results so it doesn't create any confusion that a row only contains 2 names.

Comment: Why don't you get the results and try out with c# or whatever language you are using?

Comment: @freebird: I have 3 million records. Do you mean I should process 3 million records in my C# code instead of handling this at DB level? I don't have that much memory really to hold 3 million records in memory. I have to support paging, filtering ability too.

Comment: That is understood but what you are trying to do at the db level should probably have a solution too.

Comment: Is the data in that column consistent? Your example shows name - semicolon - space - name, but also shows a row without the space.

Comment: @jlnorsworthy: Yes, please assume that data is consistent. I can handle that. That is not such big of an issue as writing the group by query. Just assume that names are split by ;

Comment: If it is a possibility, I would look at normalizing the design. Ie, adding a Inventors table that allows a one-to-many relationship between Inventions and Inventors. This would allow for much easier querying.

Comment: @armen: True, that would have been the easiest solution. However, this DB is given to us by different company. We can't normalize it.

Comment: @Jack Ah too bad. Perhaps creating a temp table to put the inventors into, then performing your query, then removing the temp table. Creating the temp table should be straight forward, all you need to do is split on ';' and trim. Might be easier than a query to deal with the data as is. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this. I certainly do not recommend this way if you have lots of data, BUT you can do some modifications and use it and it works like a charm!

This is the new code for supporting unlimited splits:

```
Declare @Table  Table   (
    Name    Nvarchar(50)
);

Insert  @Table  (
    Name
)   Select  'Hundley; Edward; Anna'
Union   Select  'Isler; Hunsberger'
Union   Select  'Hunsberger; Hundley'
Union   Select  'Anna'
;

With    Result  (
    Part
,   Remained
,   [Index]
,   Level
)   As  (
    Select  Case    When    CharIndex(';', Name, 1) =   0
            Then    Name
            Else    Left(Name, CharIndex(';', Name, 1) - 1)
        End
    ,   Right(Name, Len(Name) - CharIndex(';', Name, 1))
    ,   CharIndex(';', Name, 1)
    ,   1
        From    @Table
Union   All
    Select  LTrim(
        Case    When    CharIndex(';', Remained, 1) =   0
            Then    Remained
            Else    Left(Remained, CharIndex(';', Remained, 1) - 1)
        End
    )
    ,   Right(Remained, Len(Remained) - CharIndex(';', Remained, 1))
    ,   CharIndex(';', Remained, 1)
    ,   Level
    +   1
        From    Result
        Where   [Index] <>  0
)   Select  Part
    ,   Count(*)
        From    Result
        Group   By  Part
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for rows that have more than 2 names. Eg. If I change 1st row from Hundley; Edward to Hundley; Edward; Ana I get erroneous results

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as  
( 
    select 1 as Item, 1 as Start, CHARINDEX(';',inventors, 1) as Split, Inventors from YourInventorsTable
    union all 
    select cte.Item+1, cte.Split+1, nullif(CHARINDEX(';',inventors, cte.Split+1),0), inventors as Split 
    from cte 
    where cte.Split<>0   
)    

select rTRIM(lTRIM(SUBSTRING(inventors, start,isnull(split,len(inventors)+1)-start))), count(*)
from cte  
group by rTRIM(lTRIM(SUBSTRING(inventors, start,isnull(split,len(inventors)+1)-start)))
```

Comment: Thanks podiluska. This is so easy to read and understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [split function](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) to split the col values

```
select splittedValues.items,count(splittedValues) from table1
cross apply dbo.split(col1,';') splittedValues
group by splittedValues.items
```

[DEMO in Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90157/1)

Answer (score 0):

first make one function who take your comma or any other operator(;) separated string into one table and by using that temp table, apply GROUP function on that  table.

So you will get count for separate value.

**"select d.number,count(*) from (select number from dbo.CommaseparedListToTable('Hundley;Edward;Ana;Isler;Hunsberger;Hunsberger;Hundley',';'))d 
group by d.number"**

Answer (score 0):

```
  
    declare @text nvarchar(255) = 'Edward; Hundley; AnaIsler; Hunsberger; Hunsberger; Hundley ';
    declare @table table(id int identity,name varchar(50));

    while @text like '%;%'
    Begin
    insert into @table (name)
    select SUBSTRING(@text,1,charindex(';',@text)-1)
    set @text = SUBSTRING(@text, charindex(';',@text)+1,LEN(@text))
    end 
    insert into @table (name)
    select @text
    select name , count(name ) counts from @table group by name
```

**Output**

```
name      count 
AnaIsler    1
Hundley     2
Hunsberger  2
Edward      1
```